# Relative path for image url in CSS?

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I currently have an image saved in a folder in the following location:
**C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\image**
where **image.jpg** is the name of the image.

and I have my CSS in a folder in the following location:
**C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\css** where **stylesheet2** is the name of the style sheet.

I am trying to use relative pathing to insert a background image in my CSS.  I am trying to use

```
background-image: url("../image/image.jpg");
```

but it's not working for some reason.  I have also tried

```
background-image: url("../Image/image.jpg");
```

to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try use `../../` to back for the project root and if you're using vscode I advise you to use a extension for help you see the path, as you put a path it shows all the folders available in this path, so it is easier to know if the path is correct or wrong
I use "Path Intellisense", I hope this is useful for you too

Comment: can you just try to open `localhost/project1/image/image.jpg` in your browser to see whether it is accessible?